# MVC pass Model to child partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Let me explain my question with following example.

I am working on a website having views:

Country.cshtml (This is parent view)

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
@html.Partial("_States", Model)
```

_States.cshtml has child partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_Cities", Model)
```

_Cities.cshtml code:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
...
}
```

How should I pass Model in Country.cshml to _Cities.html?

Comment: Can you post your Model definition also? What should _cities.cshtml show?

Comment: Do the method you have shown don't work? You just need to pass the @Html.Partial("~/relative/path/to/partial", Model), and have the correct model in that partial, e.g. @model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>

Comment: It sounds like you're using partials, when you should really just be using EditorTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same model in your partials as in your parent view, according to the model you are passing. You should have the correct model referenced in the @model directive at the top of your partials that will use that model. So try something like the version below:

Country.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
@html.Partial("_States", Model) // passing Model of type IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
```

_States.cshtml has child partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
.... // some other code
@Html.Partial("_Cities", Model) // passing Model of type IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
.... // some more code
```

_Cities.cshtml code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
.... // some code.
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    ....
    // iterate the items in the Model.
}
```

If you have a property in your model that you would like to pass you could do that also:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcExample.Models.Countries>
@html.Partial("_States", Model.States) // passing model of type IEnumerable<State> maybe?
```